# How to impose minute restrictions on xsd:dateTime?

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation, xsd.exe, xsd2code, xsd-1.1

I have read that we can use minInclusive and maxInclusive restrictions on xsd:datetime fields. But how can I make sure that my dateTime field shall not occur more than 5 minutes into the future? 
I know how to handle it in java . But I want the validation at the schema level.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

This **can be done using XSD 1.1**. Example:

```
<xs:element name="myDateTime">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime">
            <xs:assertion test="$value lt (current-dateTime() + xs:dayTimeDuration('PT5M'))"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Explantion:

`current-dateTime() + xs:dayTimeDuration('PT5M')` sums 5 minutes to current date.

`lt` stands for lower than as the character `<` cannot be used at that part.

`$value` holds the value in an XSD 1.1 assertion.

See also: [xs:dayTimeDuration at XPath 2.0 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#dt-dayTimeDuration)